# Clicking on keyboard will create 3-7 characters

Tags: c++, input, operating-system, keyboard, kernel

### Summarize The Problem

I'm building an **operating system** using **C++** on **Linux Mint** in **Parallels Desktop Mac**.

I just added keyboard support except there was a problem...

When I press one key on the keyboard, it will create around 5 or more characters. This is an image of the problem:

[image: Image of problem]

### Describe What you've tried

All of the sources were talking about Linux kernel so I couldn't find anything. I didn't try anything.

### Show some code

**print.h**

```cpp
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H

#include "types.h"
#include "colours.h"


class print {
public:
    void printf(char *str);

    void printf(int num);

    void itoa(int num, char *number);

    uint32_t digit_count(int num);

    uint32_t strlen(const char *str);

    void print_char(char ch);

    void newLine();

    void init_vga(uint8_t fore_color, uint8_t back_color);

    void clear_vga_buffer(uint16_t **buffer, uint8_t fore_color, uint8_t back_color);

    uint16_t vga_entry(unsigned char ch, uint8_t fore_color, uint8_t back_color);

    void setTextColors(uint8_t foreColor, uint8_t back_color);

    print *getPrinter();

    void setPrinter(print *printer1);

private:
    print *ksafdkjlasdlfk;
    //index for video buffer array
    uint32_t vga_index;
    //counter to store new lines
    uint32_t next_line_index = 1;
    //fore & back color values
    uint8_t g_fore_color = WHITE, g_back_color = BLUE;
    //digit ascii code for printing integers
    int digit_ascii_codes[10] = {0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39};
#define VGA_ADDRESS 0xB8000
#define BUFSIZE 2200

    uint16_t *vga_buffer;

#define NULL 0

};

#endif
```

**print.cpp**

```cpp
#include "print.h"


void print::printf(char *str) {
    uint32_t index = 0;
    while (str[index]) {
        print_char(str[index]);
        index++;
    }
}

void print::printf(int num) {
    char str_num[digit_count(num) + 1];
    itoa(num, str_num);
    printf(str_num);
}

void print::itoa(int num, char *number) {
    int dgcount = digit_count(num);
    int index = dgcount - 1;
    char x;
    if (num == 0 && dgcount == 1) {
        number[0] = '0';
        number[1] = '\0';
    } else {
        while (num != 0) {
            x = num % 10;
            number[index] = x + '0';
            index--;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        number[dgcount] = '\0';
    }
}

uint32_t print::digit_count(int num) {
    uint32_t count = 0;
    if (num == 0)
        return 1;
    while (num > 0) {
        count++;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return count;
}

uint32_t print::strlen(const char *str) {
    uint32_t length = 0;
    while (str[length])
        length++;
    return length;
}

void print::print_char(char ch) {
    vga_buffer[vga_index] = vga_entry(ch, g_fore_color, g_back_color);
    vga_index++;
}

void print::newLine() {
    if (next_line_index >= 55) {
        next_line_index = 0;
        clear_vga_buffer(&vga_buffer, g_fore_color, g_back_color);
    }
    vga_index = 80 * next_line_index;
    next_line_index++;
}

void print::init_vga(uint8_t fore_color, uint8_t back_color) {
    vga_buffer = (uint16_t *) VGA_ADDRESS;
    clear_vga_buffer(&vga_buffer, fore_color, back_color);
    g_fore_color = fore_color;
    g_back_color = back_color;
}

void print::clear_vga_buffer(uint16_t **buffer, uint8_t fore_color, uint8_t back_color) {
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++) {
        (*buffer)[i] = vga_entry(NULL, fore_color, back_color);
    }
    next_line_index = 1;
    vga_index = 0;
}

uint16_t print::vga_entry(unsigned char ch, uint8_t fore_color, uint8_t back_color) {
    uint16_t ax = 0;
    uint8_t ah = 0, al = 0;

    ah = back_color;
    ah <<= 4;
    ah |= fore_color;
    ax = ah;
    ax <<= 8;
    al = ch;
    ax |= al;

    return ax;
}

void print::setTextColors(uint8_t foreColor, uint8_t back_color) {
    g_fore_color = foreColor;
    g_back_color = back_color;
}

print *print::getPrinter() {
    return ksafdkjlasdlfk;
}

void print::setPrinter(print *printer1) {
    ksafdkjlasdlfk = printer1;
}
```

**keyboard.h**

```cpp
#ifndef APOS_KEYBOARD_H
#define APOS_KEYBOARD_H

#include "../../utils/types.h"
#include "../../utils/print.h"
#include "char.h"

class keyboard {
public:
    void enableKeyboard();

    void test_input();

    void sleep(uint32_t timer_count);

    void wait_for_io(uint32_t timer_count);

    char get_input_keycode();

    void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t data);

    uint8_t inb(uint16_t port);
};


#endif //APOS_KEYBOARD_H
```

**keyboard.cpp**

```cpp
#include "keyboard.h"


uint8_t keyboard::inb(uint16_t port) {
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "d"(port));
    return ret;
}

void keyboard::outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t data) {
    asm volatile("outb %0, %1" : "=a"(data) : "d"(port));
}

char keyboard::get_input_keycode() {
    char ch = 0;
    while ((ch = inb(KEYBOARD_PORT)) != 0) {
        if (ch > 0)
            return ch;
    }
    return ch;
}

/*
keep the cpu busy for doing nothing(nop)
so that io port will not be processed by cpu
here timer can also be used, but lets do this in looping counter
*/
void keyboard::wait_for_io(uint32_t timer_count) {
    while (1) {
        asm volatile("nop");
        timer_count--;
        if (timer_count <= 0)
            break;
    }
}

void keyboard::sleep(uint32_t timer_count) {
    wait_for_io(timer_count);
}

void keyboard::test_input() {
    char ch = 0;
    char keycode = 0;
    do {
        keycode = get_input_keycode();
        if (keycode == KEY_ENTER) {
            print printt;
            printt.getPrinter()->newLine();
        } else {
            ch = get_ascii_char(keycode);
            print printt;
            printt.getPrinter()->print_char(ch);
        }
        sleep(0x02FFFFFF);
    } while (ch > 0);
}

void keyboard::enableKeyboard() {
    test_input();
}
```

The `kernel.cpp` just has the `test_intput` command and prints a few things.

There are a few files there, but that main ones are the `kernel.cpp`, hardware/keyboard/all the files there.

Comment: Please post the shortest possible code _relevant to the problem_, instead of linking us off-site to your project.

Comment: Ok, I will do so

Comment: Ok, I added the code to the question

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service.  What have you tried so far to troubleshoot the issue yourself?

Comment: I have set the timer to 1 second it works but takes 10 seconds print a character

Answer (score 0):

Either use a seperate Thread to handle the input reckognition function, that way you can use a sleep without blocking the main Thread. You could also save the current pressed key and save it as a previous key and check if it has changed, if not the button has not been released yet. so you can avoid multiples.